# JAX-RS(CXF) JSONProvider

Tags: rest, cxf, jax-rs

I am new to JAX-RS, I am just starting with apache CXF, I am struck at "No message body writer has been found for response class" while trying to return "application/jason". I know, I can set the JSONProvider using spring context loader file, but I dont want to use   spring. Is there any way to set JSONProvider to the application directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in my code, instead "application/json" I wrote "application/jason", I corrected it, and it is working. And I found that no need to set JSON Provider explicitly.